# Store register's data in a variable in Assembly

Tags: variables, assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I wrote a program in assembly language using emu8086 IDE that adds up 2 bytes type variables and store the result in another variable .

Here is my program :

```
 xor ax,ax
 mov al,a
 mov al,b
 mov c,ax

 ret

 a db 2h
 b db 3h
 c dw ?
```

But while compiling this program the following error message showed up:

```
(8) mov c,ax
(8) error: invalid operand.
```

Can someone help me to solve this problem

Comment: `mov c, ax` looks right to me; emu8086's assembler should infer `mov word ptr ds:[c], ax` from that.  Unless `c` is a reserved name or something?  The problem is probably elsewhere, perhaps the fact that there's do `section` or `segment` directive around your data variables?  Without at least an `org 100h` for a `.com` program, I'm not sure that can execute correctly.  IDK enough about emu8086 to say for sure, but maybe start with a working program that uses variables as a template, and replace its code + variables with yours.